# Mspaint in commandline

Tags: python

I converted images (using imagemagick) from png to bmp. 
Trying to analyze the bmp with Python Simplecv

```
img=Image('im.bmp')
```

returns an error from PIL:
    .....IOError: Unsupported BMP header type (124)

When I convert the image with mspaint, no error is returned.

Consequently, as I have a lot of images to convert, does anybody knows how to save an image with mspaint.
I can open paint but how to save the image ?
Thanks a lot in advance for any clue
Dom

Comment: I think you might have more luck reconverting them in ImageMagick and using a different BMP format. MS Paint cannot be automated other than a few simple things like opening a file and printing.

Comment: "How to save an image with mspaint". You can just `ctrl + s` or `file > save | save as` ? Whats wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just working on something similar, below code has worked for me but I'm not sure how to close paint now I've done:

```
import os
import ImageGrab
SaveDirectory=r'C:\Users\????\Desktop'
sName = "Name of File"
ImageEditorPath=r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe'
img=ImageGrab.grab()
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,sName + '.bmp')
img.save(saveas)
editorstring='""%s" "%s"'% (ImageEditorPath,saveas) 
os.system(editorstring)
```